# Deploy image to kubernetes without storing the image in a dockerhub

Tags: docker, maven, kubernetes, docker-maven-plugin

I'm trying to migrate from docker-maven-plugin to kubernetes-maven-plugin for an test-setup for local development and jenkins-builds. The point of the setup is to eliminate differences between the local development and the jenkins-server. Since docker built the image, the image is stored in the local repository and doesn't have to be uploaded to a central server where the base-images are located. So we can basically verify our build without uploading anything to the server and the images is discarded after the task is done (running integrationstests).

Is there a similar way to trick kubernetes to store the image into the local repository without having to take the roundtrip to a central repository? Eg, behave as if the image is already downloaded? Note that I still need to fetch the base-image from the central repository.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use any docker repo (public or private), you can use what is called [Pre-pulled-images](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#pre-pulled-images).
This is a bit annoying as you need to make sure all the kubernetes nodes have the images there and also set the [ImagePullPolicy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#image-pull-policy) to `Never` in every kubernetes manifest.

In your case, if what you call local repository is some private docker registry, you just need to store the credentials to the private registry in a kubernetes secret and either patch you default service account with `ImagePullSecrets` or your actual deployment/pod manifest. More details about that https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/